# New operating system security

Tags: security, operating-system, malware

So I was messing around looking at different ways to operate a computer under total security. I found ways people were using specialized operating systems like [Tails](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tails_%28operating_system%29) and that got me thinking, could a computer be secured by running an operating system that nobody has ever seen?

Obviously this would take a lot of work to make an OS from the ground up without any help, but would that be safe? Could having no information available about an OS make it invulnerable to attack?

P.S. I am talking about anti-hacking and anti-malware, not private web browsing.

Comment: Well, if nobody has ever seen it AND you don't connect it to the internet, it will be safe :) Off-topic here, though. I think there's a security stack exchange now, though I don't have its URL handy.

Comment: Having no information available about an OS would make it unuseable for anything.  OTOH, writing the API documentation would be really easy, (can I have the contract to do it?).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What you're suggesting sounds a lot like [security through obscurity](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Security_through_obscurity).

Firstly, there's the issue that if you write your own operating system from ground up, it won't have exposure to close scrutiny and it's very likely you would have undiscovered exploitable bugs and vulnerabilities. A lot like cryptography, anyone can design a secure operating system that they, themselves, can't break into. Unfortunately, there's always someone in the world that's smarter than you who *will* be able to break in.

Secondly (and following up on the first point), the entire security of your architecture will essentially rely on the secrecy of your implementation. The moment someone manages to get a copy of your operating system or source code, you can be sure the security of your whole system will come crashing down like a ton of bricks before you can finish saying "oops". This is a very fragile defence against attack.

Lastly, there's no provable 'invulnerable to attack'. The closest thing to it is to have as many people using it as possible and hope the good guys find the vulnerabilities before the bad guys. But then you'd be back to square one since this is pretty much what most major operating systems already do.